# How should I go about inserting a layout and what layout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

So here is what I have so far, I will be adding a lot more in but here is my so called skeleton. What I am having trouble doing is deciding what layout I should use, if I should just make my own, and how will I go about doing that?

Some information about my creation will be useful: I am going to have multiple tags and input spaces to the right of them on the left-most area of the GUI, on the bottom right there will be a button, and on the top right there will be a textbox that will constantly stream information of what the bot is doing.

Please help me to find a layout I can use and tell me how to easily implement it (FYI I am using Ubuntu).

[image: An example of the desired layout]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class dogedice {

    public static void createWindow() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Framework Michael+Dalin");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to the framework of our future bots!");
        JLabel textLabel2 = new JLabel("Username");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField("Username");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();// Any new parts must be added here!
        panel.add(textLabel);
        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(textLabel2);

        textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 750));
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide ASCII art (or an image with a simple drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: Added and I am not sure what size atm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First take a look at [the Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Then, you'll notice that with a little creativity, you can achieve just about any desired layout either with just one layout manager or a combination of several for all your components.

Based on your description, you could use a `BorderLayout` with a `JPanel` in each of the quadrants.

- In the SOUTH quadrant, a `FlowLayout` could be used with a right alignment.
- In the WEST quadrant, a `GridBagLayout` could be used to create two columns, one for the tag (which I assumed was a `JLabel`) and one for an input space (`JTextField`).
- In the CENTER quadrant, the text area can be used to display output (`JTextArea` encapsulated in a `JScrollPanel`)

Here's an example:

[image: JFrame with multiple layout managers]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class LayoutExample1 extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    LayoutExample1 frame = new LayoutExample1();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public LayoutExample1() {
        setTitle("Title of GUI");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0};
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        JLabel lblTag = new JLabel("Tag 1");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_lblTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_lblTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblTag.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(lblTag, gbc_lblTag);

        textField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textField.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 5));

        JButton btnConfirm = new JButton("Confirm");
        panel_1.add(btnConfirm);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("I am a bot and I will tell you what I am doing to your systems!");
        textArea.setColumns(20);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

        pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: David, one question... I added another label with y=1 and I wanted to know how to add a second text imput box because I don't know where the title goes for them...

Comment: @michaeladair It is exactly the same as the currently added labels and text fields. Just change the ```gridx``` and ```gridy``` values to the next number where y is the row and x is the column.

Comment: But then I get this error:
dogedice.java:65: error: variable gbc_textField is already defined in constructor dogedice()
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
                           ^
1 error

Comment: You're defining the variable twice when it is already defined. Give it a different name or remove the identifier in front of the variable name. Please go through the basics of Java programming first and then go through the Visual Guide of Layout Managers as you need to understand why the code works the way it does or else you will continue to be plagued with errors.

Answer (score 0):

If the UI is that simple, put all the tags and inputs in a JPanel with GridLayout and put it in the center of a mainPanel with BorderLayout.

If you are interested in a more complex layout and want to learn how to use one, I recommend http://miglayout.com/

Comment: Not really sure how to do that xD, the fact of the matter is that I do not know a lot of Java coding. Tried tutorials and stuff before, hands-on works more for me so its a learn as I go process. Would you mind showing how to do that?